# Why does Tom Hanks' character never open up the last package?

Tags: character, cast-away

During his time on the island in [*Cast Away*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162222/), Chuck Noland (Tom Hanks) never opens up one last FedEx package, even though it could have made his escape or his survival easier. Why is this?

Comment: Some people are a stickler for _integrity_! Guess Tom Hank's character was one of those...

Comment: Actually, he opens all the packages except one

Comment: Where did the ice skates come from? Or his "fishing  net"? Or... Wilson!

Comment: in an earlier draft of the movie, he eventually does open the last package, and it contains something mostly useless (some salsa I think). As @SystemDown points out, leaving it unopened makes a much bigger point about his character.

Comment: To restate what was already answered, but in different terms, it gave him something to hope for, a sense of urgency and a distraction. Protecting the package so that he may finally deliver it is a good way to stay sane.

Comment: There was a hilarious TV commercial where he delivers it and the lady is like: “Oh! My satellite phone and GPS receiver with extra batteries!”

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Tom Hanks's character works for FedEx, and sees it as his job that the package reaches its intended destination safe and sound, and most importantly unopened. While the package remains closed he still has a chance to deliver it. And delivering it means that he gets off the island.

It was a way of keeping himself sane and keeping his hopes up.

Comment: Sane, _in contrast to going nuts_ and **talking with Wilson the face-ball**

Comment: @nilon: I disagree. If he had not had Wilson, his social skills would've atrophied. He's better off talking to a ball than withdraw inside his own mind. This is very similar to why toddlers are incentivized to consider their stuffed animals as individuals; it lets them practice social skills with no real consequences for failing. Failing isn't the issue for Tom Hanks' character, but practicing (maintaining) social skills is relevant.

Comment: @Flater I don't disagree with your idea, nor from SystemDown. Sanity and craziness live together.

Comment: Matches up with [the Super Bowl commercial](https://adland.tv/commercials/fedex-castaway-desert-island-2003-045-usa), so it must be the right answer! "I swore that I would deliver it for you *because I work for FedEx*…By the way, what's in the package?"

Answer (score 1):

The package had a picture of wings which represented to him staying alive. Getting off the island was a bonus. If not for the sail 4 years later, he had no plans on leaving, so it was pure luck he was found. The package was motivation so that's why he protected it and didn't open it. If he did, he would likely kill himself, die from depression, get sick, etc.

Comment: Hi - welcome to Movies & TV. I am glad that you are getting into answering this question, but we generally prefer that people back up their answers/explain why their answers are correct. If you could elaborate on and explain your answer, that would be wonderful!

Comment: @ghostdog This answer offers no more sourcing than the accepted answer, with 42 votes as of now.